# Creating bat file for copying folder from one directory to the other: answering cmd questions beforehand

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have `.bat` file like this:

```
xcopy "C:\sourcepath\sourcefoldername" "C:\resultpath\sourcefoldername" /E
```

It copied `sourcefoldername` from `C:\sourcepath` to `C:\resultpath`. However, when I run it, if there's already `C:\resultpath\sourcefoldername`, it asks me if I want to replace all of its contents (I need to enter A). If there's no `C:\resultpath\sourcefoldername` it asks me if `sourcefoldername` is a file or directory (I need to enter D).

Is there a way to include answers in the code so that no input from me would be required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "\" character at the end of the destination directory tell to xcopy that the destination is a directory (an then xcopy don't ask you).
The /Y switch tell to xcopy to override the file without ask for a confirmation.

```
xcopy "C:\sourcepath\sourcefoldername" "C:\resultpath\sourcefoldername\" /E /Y
```